# IndexError: list index out of range Где скрыта ошибка?

Tags: python

```
a =[[15, -4],[8, 3]]
m = 2
n = 2
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):              
        if j-1 < 0:
            j-1 == n-1
        elif j+1 > n-1:
            j+1 == 0
        elif i-1 < 0:
            i-1 == m-1
        elif i+1 > m-1:
            i+1 == 0
        summ = a[i][j-1] + a[i][j+1] + a[i+1][j] + a[i-1][j]   
        print(summ, '', end = '')
    print()
```

Comment: `a[i][j+1]` и тут `a[i+1][j]`. У Вас `i` будет 1+1, а такого элемента уже нет

Comment: `[j+1]` даёт выход за пределы списка и кроме того вы понимаете, что все ваши `if` не работают, поскольку внутри просто идет сравнение, а не присваивание?